# Change Sender's Address based on lists in SharePoint workflow mails

Tags: sharepoint-designer

SharePoint Designer workflow which sends mail is configured on List A and List B. Is there a way we could change the FROM address of the email in inbox to appear List A(abc@abc.com) for List A and List B(abc@abc.com) for List B?

I am sure this could be implemented site level but not sure about list level.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry...i don't understand your question.

Comment: basically i need different from address for different lists

Comment: Did you mean send an email from workflow defining two different sender, accordingly list A and/or list B?

Comment: yes.Based on list, sender's address or name should change

Comment: like in case of sites. Site A will take 'Site A' as display name of sender.Site B sender's display name will be 'Site B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify the FROM address for email messages when you use the "Send an email" option from a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow action.

I found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2014/10/24/you-cant-specify-the-from-address-for-email-messages-when-you-use-the-send-an-email-option-from-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-action/) article, but i did not find a Microsoft documentation regarding it.

However I had the same problem, I installed a SharePoint plugin called [I Love Sharepoint](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/). It is for 2010, if you want/need you have to adapt id programmatically to 2013. In includes more then a workaraound to this problem; reed the docs for more information.

After that `I` would create a workflow for each list...